# How can I take data from fstream and then take it again?

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream

I'm a begginer at c++, so I wanted to ask, how can I take data from `fstream`
after I already took all the data from it?

I have done something like this

```
fstream file;
string data, key, key2;
while(file>>data)
{
    key += data;
}
```

Now I want to do it again with the same file but without re-open it:

```
while(file>>data)
{
    key2 += data;
}
```

How can I do that with `fstream`?

Comment: with the code above you can also copy your data `key2 = key' or adding the data to both values in the same loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Rewind* the stream:

```
file.clear();
file.seekg(0);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I know it's probebly silly question but you realy helped me alot!

Comment: Also consider `void rewind ( FILE * stream );` from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/